# Message box not working with page redirect

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to display a confirmation popup box before the response.redirect occurs. When I use the code below, I never get a popup it just redirects. Any idea what I am missing?

```
Try
        Dim msg As String = "Hello!"
        Dim script As String = "alert('" & msg & "');"
        script += "window.location.href ='frmSummary.aspx'"
        'Navigate to Page 2
        'Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "SCRIPT", script,true);
        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Test",       script, True)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try



    Response.Redirect("~/frmMain.aspx")
```

Comment: Your VB code is executing at the server.  The redirect happens *before* any code gets sent to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to hazard a guess that it's directing to `frmMain.aspx`..?

You are attempting to render your Javascript on the client, though before the page gets rendered you're performing a redirect with this line - `Response.Redirect("~/frmMain.aspx")`

Try commenting that redirect out and trying again.

Comment: Yes, it works when I comment out the redirect. Is there a way I can have it redirect after the user clicks ok on the messagebox?

Comment: is it not redirecting to 'frmSummary.aspx' after the click?

Comment: I need it to redirec to frmMain after the ok click

Comment: So change `script += "window.location.href ='frmSummary.aspx'"` to `script += "window.location.href ='frmMain.aspx'"`

Answer (score 2):

Put the `window.location.href` logic into a `JavaScript confirm` instead of an `alert` call, like this:

```
if (confirm("Do you want to do something?")) {
    // User clicked OK, so redirect
    window.location.href = 'frmSummary.aspx';
}
```

Comment: How can I trap the OK click in a javascript? I never did that before Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I realized that you need to use a `confirm`, not an `alert`. I updated my answer. `alert` does not return a value, but `confirm` does.

Answer (score 2):

In your current code, the server redirects to frmMain.aspx before rendering back to client side.

If you want to display something back to user with OK/Cancel button, you want something like this -

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string script = "if(confirm('Are you sure ...?')) {window.location.href ='frmSummary.aspx'; }";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Test", script, true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own pop-up dialog using html/css and a little bit to js. Another way is to create a js function that handles a confirmation dialog... http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp